How to create a reverse proxy server for my react.js App that get build folder from aws s3 bucket to work All the routes?
I put my react build folder on AWS S3 bucket so i want to make a reverse proxy server to run my react build folder through S3 bucket url that work on every route.
I tried to make a reverse proxy server but it is only work with Home route, other routes not working. If i Copy and paste url so it was not working.
const express = require('express')
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy')
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const path = require('path');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: '',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: '',
        secretAccessKey: ''
    }
})

const app = express()
const PORT = 8000

const BASE_PATH = 'https://s3.com/__outputs'

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxy()


app.use("/*", async (req, res) => {
    const hostname = req.hostname;
    const subdomain = hostname.split('.')[0];

    // Custom Domain - DB Query

    const resolvesTo = `${BASE_PATH}/${subdomain}`


    return proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: resolvesTo,
        changeOrigin: true
    })

})
proxy.on('proxyReq', async (proxyReq, req, res) => {
    const url = req.url;

    console.log(url, "fielpath")

    if (url === '/') {
        proxyReq.path += 'index.html'
    }

})
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Reverse Proxy Running..${PORT}`))





You do not need an additional reverse proxy server for hosting a static website.
You can use an Amazon CloudFront distribution to serve a static website .
This is way faster, cheaper, and needs less maintenance and running your own reverse proxy.
